# WooCommerce Checkout Stuck on Spinning

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When Checking Out, order details on the right column are stuck on loading: https://ellasbubbles.com/checkout/

You can add a product to your cart here: https://ellasbubbles.com/walk-in-tub-accessory-pricing/

I have read 30+ threads and tutorials on resolving this. I have tried to remove all plugins, reset .htaccess, reset functions.php, up memory limit, change index.html to php, you name it. This thread is being created to assist in resolution

I did notice that there is no ?wc-ajax=checkout in my XHR

Thank you for any additional assistance

UPDATE, this resolution does seem to work - but it seems like a last resort. What is causing the issue in the first place and how can it be resolved?:

```
/* Fix issues with jquery overlay blocking checkout button */
.woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay {
  position: relative!important;
  display: none!important;
}
```

UPDATE, https://ellasbubbles.com/?wc-ajax=update_order_review is returning -1

Comment: Check your console for errors. There's a script being output to the document with an empty if() conditional. `if() {
       document.documentElement.classList.add('gn-dark-mode');
      }`

Comment: This is a plugin, I disabled this plugin and nothing changed

Comment: https://ellasbubbles.com/?wc-ajax=update_order_review is returning -1

Comment: New js error referencing 'gn-toggle-button'.

Comment: Removing this plugin and error does not resolve the issue

Comment: You did not remove the error. The JS throwing the error still exists. You must be confused as to what plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: I removed the error by disabling the plugin... tested... didn't work..... and re-enabled